# Why isn't my base case returning the appropriate array?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm practicing recursion and the prompt is to "Write a recursive function where given an array of words, return a new array where each word is capitalized". I understand it'd be pretty straightforward to approach this iteratively, but this is for the purpose of practicing recursion.

```
function capitalizeWords (arr, i = 0) {
  if (i === arr.length) return arr;
  arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
  capitalizeWords(arr, i+=1);
}

let words = ['i', 'am', 'learning', 'recursion'];
capitalizeWords(words);
```

My function returns `undefined`. I console.logged `arr` to check if it's getting updated appropriately and it is. But when returning `arr` with my base case, it seems to lose some reference to the value of the arr. Have no idea how this isn't working.

I ran my code through Python Tutor, but I don't understand what's exactly happening when my function fulfills my base case condition.
[image: Before arr is supposed to be returned]
[image: After arr is supposed to be returned]

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing the return statement:

```js
function capitalizeWords (arr, i = 0) {
  if (i === arr.length) return arr;
  arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
  return capitalizeWords(arr, i+=1);
}
```

FYI - this modifies the original array as well. So calling the function changes the `words` array. If you want it to be immutable (not affecting the original `words` array), you can do the following:

```js
function capitalizeWords (arr) {
  return arr.map(function (part) {
    if (Array.isArray(part)) {
      return capitalizeWords(part);
    }
    return part.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

With your code in your question - that is actually modifying the `words` array. If you run `console.log(words)` you'll see that it has changed.

Comment: Oh gosh duh. Thanks for catching that. 

I'm cautious to accept your alternative using arr.map(), however. Under the hood, map is just a loop that returns a new array, which I guess theoretically you can build with either a recursive or iterative loop. I've rebuilt the map method before and used a for loop myself, which is not a recursive approach.

Comment: To modify your 2nd alternative and keep to a recursive approach, I would add another parameter (say "output" initialized to [ ] ), push my results to that, and then return output when my base case hits.

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed my answer to make the immutable function recursive.